# ¿Cómo puedo usar un bucle for para saber si un número x es divisible entre otro?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Letra del ejercicio:

> Suponga que debe verificar si un número dado X es divisible
>   entre otro Y, pero no dispone de las operaciones división
>   ni resto de la división entera. ¿Podría utilizar una estructura de tipo `for` para resolver?

He estado tratando de implementar el `for`, pero sinceramente no lo he conseguido.

Ahora les pasó uno de los intentos con ese bucle, tengan en cuenta que soy un estudiante de primer año, y me cuesta un montón:

```
def divi(x,y):
    x > y and y != 0
    contador = 1
    guardaste = 0
    for número in (contador):
        if x == y*1:
            return(x + "es divisible entre" + y)
            contador = contador + 1
        else:
            print("ingrese nuevos valores númericos para (x,y)")
```

Answer (score 2):

Con el mecanismo de repetir la resta a `x` del valor de `y` hasta ver si llegamos al valor exacto de `y`,  entonces podemos afirmar que `x` es múltiplo de `y`, para eso nos apoyamos en `range(Desde, Hasta, Paso)`, como el límite hasta es no inclusivo debemos hacer `y - y` para poder verificar si el último valor de `i` es igual a `y`:

```
def is_multiplo(x,y):

    # Casos no válidos
    if y > x or x == 0 or y == 0:
      return False

    for i in range(x, y-y, -y):
      if i == y:
        return True

    return False


print(is_multiplo(101,2))
print(is_multiplo(100,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Me cuesta pensar de una forma en la que podrías usar un for para esto, ya que lo complicaría demasiado y un `while` hace todo mucho mejor.

Aquí está la solución con un while:

```
def is_multi(x, y):
    assert x > y != 0

    x1 = x

    while x1 > 0:

        x1 -= y

    if x1 != 0 or x1 < 0:
        print("Los numeros {} y {} NO son multiplos".format(x, y))
    elif x1 == 0:
        print("Los numeros {} y {} SI son multiplos".format(x, y))

# Prueba


is_multi(17, 3)
is_multi(15, 7)
is_multi(20,5)
is_multi(14, 7)
is_multi(120, 5)
is_multi(10000000, 2)
```

Podrías tratar de modificarlo para que se acomode a un for, pero la verdad, te desearía mucha suerte con eso xD.

Puedes jugar con éste código y si encuentras algún error, déjame saber!

Saludos, Azmitia

Answer (score 0):

A mi se me ocurre que podrias hacer, en el sentido estricto de x es divisible por y:

```
def son_divisibles(a, b):
    if b > a:
        b, a = a, b
    return 0 in xrange(a, -1, -b)

def es_divisible(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return True
    elif x == y:
        return True
    elif x > y:
        return son_divisibles(x, y)
    else:
        return False
```

Si por el contrario, solo quieres saber si uno es multiplo del otro, puedes usar `son_divisibles(a, b)`. Espero que sea de ayuda.